# Respect of children

Tags: parents, children, respect

What if parents disrespect their children.
Some time parents disrespect their own children they abuse their children. We often heared about the rights of parents but what about rights of children of age more than 20  who are still depending on their parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Although the father deserves to be warned (of divine punishment) for his sin and neglect of shar‘i duties, disobedient children and those who do not treat their parents kindly are also warned about their actions; **it is not permissible to repay mistreatment with mistreatment or wrongdoing with wrongdoing**.
>
> Thirdly:
>
> Although children are not to be blamed for feelings of resentment in the heart towards the father who commits sin or is a disbeliever, that **does not contradict the duty to treat him kindly and obey him in that which is right and proper**. But **you have to hold your tongue and refrain from speaking badly to him (father), and also refrain from mistreating him in practical terms**. " (https://islamqa.info/en/answers/176847/hating-an-unjust-father)

So from the aforementioned FATWA, one may conclude that **children must treat kindly with their parents even if they do injustice with their own children. Children should also follow their parents as long as it does not lead to Shirk.**

> **“But if they (both) strive with you to make you join in worship with Me others that of which you have no knowledge, then obey them not, but behave with them in the world kindly, and follow the path of him who turns to Me in repentance and in obedience. Then to Me will be your return, and I shall tell you what you used to do”
>   [31:15].**

Answer (score 1):

Protecting the rights of children is sometimes considered so great that it is also considered as protecting the privacy of parents. Traditions in which there is talk of protecting the rights of children and the sanctity of children, and sometimes this is considered so great that it is also called protection of the privacy of parents.

The Messenger of God (peace and blessings of God be upon him and his family) said:

> Just as a child should not disrespect his parents, parents should not
> disrespect him "

Or elsewhere It is stated: "The Messenger of God (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said:" Glory be to your children and make their manners good. " (Awali al-Laali al-Aziziyya fi al-Ahadith al-Diniya, Ibn Abi Jumhur, Muhammad ibn Zayn al-Din, vol. 1, p. 254, AH 11) Prophet of God (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him): Respect your children and raise them well.

Ref: https://namnak.com/%D8%AD%D9%82%D9%88%D9%82-%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86.p32192

Comment: Do you know the source of the first hadith cited?

Comment: This hadith? : Just as a child should not disrespect his parents, parents should not disrespect him "       ------------  That's it: رسولُ اللّه ِ (صلی الله علیه و آله) «یَلزَمُ الوالِدَینِ مِن عُقوقِ الوَلَدِ ما یَلزَمُ الوَلَدَ لَهُما مِن العُقوق. (من لایحضره الفقیه، شیخ صدوق، ج3، ص483، ح4705)  ----